# Validating JSON schema always return true

Tags: python, json

I've written a code that should validate my JSON schema by comparing the schema with the JSON string. It always returns True, even when instead of a given type in schema, I return a string or an int. I bet there is something that I missed in the logic of my schema to compare to.
Here is a code:

```
import json
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import validate


Emp_Schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "outputs": {
        "boundaries": {"type": "List[List[coords]]"},
        "connecter": {"type": "List[bool]"},
        "compare": {"type": "List[float]"},
        "center": {"type": "List[List[coords]]"},
        "classes": {"List[int]"},
    },
}


def validate_json(jsonData):
    try:
        validate(instance=jsonData, schema=Emp_Schema)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as error:
        return False
    return True



jsonStr = json.loads('''{
    "boundaries": [
        [
            150.05322,
            11.53223,
            300.532,
            123.1437
        ],
        [
            53.877,
            332.663879,
            49.9110756,
            441.316406
        ],
        [
            388.617188,
            298.171814,
            401.498016,
            308.061432
        ],
        [
            373.388794,
            269.419434,
            393.059235,
            284.425232
        ],
        [
            388.449,
            276.744293,
            401.1651,
            287.800415
        ],
        [
            371.061462,
            69.9721527,
            382.472076,
            81.5727
        ],
        [
            354.491974,
            147.660431,
            370.116882,
            160.380508
        ]
    ],
    "connected": [
        true,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true
    ],
    "compare": [
        0.990648627,
        0.989233553,
        0.984282315,
        0.949795425,
        0.913895547,
        0.539879441,
        0.4897542
    ],
    "center": [
        [
            369.494934,
            116.291542
        ],
        [
            40.8455315,
            332.990143
        ],
        [
            395.057587,
            303.116638
        ],
        [
            383.224,
            276.922333
        ],
        [
            394.807068,
            282.272369
        ],
        [
            376.766785,
            75.7724228
        ],
        [
            362.304443,
            154.020477
        ]
    ],
    "classes": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}''')

# calling above define function
is_valid = validate_json(jsonStr)
if is_valid :
    print('Given JSON data:\n ', jsonStr)
    print("The JSON data is valid")
else:
    print(jsonStr)
    print("The JSON data is Invalid")
```

I am new to json format, so I bet i specified my Emp_Schema variable wrong. I would be grateful for any recommendations how to make it so, only the jsonStr would pass the test. Because the json string here is the string that should be valid, and any other should return as invalid.

Comment: "even when instead of a given type in schema, I return a string or an int." I can't understand what you mean by this. If I copy and paste the code that you have shown, and run it without modification, what is it *supposed to* do? Is that different from what it actually does? If not, please fix the example [so that it actually demonstrates a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If it does, then please clearly explain what the difference is.

Comment: It should return True if the jsonStr is of the same schema as Emp_Schema. So if in 'boundaries' I return 12 instead of [ [ 12 ] ], it should return False.

Comment: Okay, so *show an example where the program does the wrong thing*.

Comment: The issue is that it does always return True. Even if I pass such json_str to it:
json_str =("{"boxes": "hey"}")
It doesn't match the schema but it still passes as proper json.

Comment: Aha. My advice is to read the [documentation](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) more closely. Make sure you can get the first example from the documentation to work. Then see if you can notice any differences between how you try to write your schema, vs. the example schema. In particular: does the example schema have a `"outputs"` key? Does your scheme have a `"properties"` key?

Comment: You might also try reading the [specification](https://json-schema.org/) for JSON schemas.

Comment: Yes, I think I got the whole idea of json schema wrong. Thanks for the advice!